# QtCreator shows different "Multiple Parse Contexts" for C++ Header

Tags: c++, qt-creator, yocto

When I open a `CMakeLists.txt` in QtCreator and import an existing build, the editor offers multiple parse contexts for each header:

[image: Active Parse Context Tooltip]

Since the first parse context in the list is chosen, all headers are parsed as `C headers` which results in a broken IDE (namespaces are not recognized, includes do not work, etc):

[image: Parse Contexts offered - C, C++, Obj-C and Obj-C++]

**Question**: Is there a chance to define the whole project as C++ project? Or select the parse context globally for all headers? What is the reason for these "multiple parse contexts"?

Answer (score 1):

I found an option to set the default "Active Parse Context" to C++: Turn off `Interpret ambiguous headers as C headers`.

[image: Interpret ambiguous headers as C headers]

In my case it helped a lot to disable also the "ClangCodeModel" since it failed to parse the files - while the built-in code model succeeds:

[image: QtCreator - Installed Plugins - ClangCodeModel]